# WPF/MVVM save the selected item in viewmodel/model

Tags: xaml, mvvm, datagrid, viewmodel, selecteditem

How must I declare the **SelectedItem** property in my **Viewmodel/Model** to save the SelectedItem from a Datagrid to it , so that the Datagrid's property SelectedItem has a Binding to the SelectedItem property in my Viewmodel/Model. **What kind of datatype I must use?**
I did a test with a String property, but if I debug the string has the value: System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Show your `ViewModel` and `View`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SelectedItem should be of the Type of which your Collection binded to the DataGrid is. Like if your Datagrid is binded with the **Collection of Type Student** , then your SelectedItem must be of Type **Student**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now i have the answer. 
I declare a selecteditem property of the datatyp DataRowView and then i bind it to the datagrids selecteditem property. then i have in my viewmodel the selected item in the DataRowView property.